# Delivery for the cult

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

From time to times Trevor Phillips will meet random people who'll ask him to drive them somewhere. Trevor can of course do it, or he can deliver them to the *Altruist Cult* instead.

I understand that the cult will reward Trevor with some money, and [there's an achievement for doing so too](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Altruist_Acolyte).

However, aside from the achievement and moral implications, what are the differences for "doing what's right" and "doing what's wrong"? Will I get more money when making a delivery for the cult? Will I get a different reward than money, when I don't?

Comment: I just completed my second random encounter of that type. There was only the "good option" this time. Turns out she's a driver that can be used during heists (maybe that's the reason I coudn't deliver her to the cult?) So it looks like if the reward is *really* important, there won't be a second option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After experimenting for a while (God bless the poor victims' souls) and with the help of the Brady guide I have compiled a handy list related to the cult.

For every victim delivered to the cult, Trevor receives $1'000. After he delivered his fourth victim, he will be "invited" by the cult, resulting in a <strike>bloodbath</strike> shootout.
Because of that, you'll have to decide which victims to deliver if you plan on exterminating the cult.

Keep in mind that only Trevor can make deliveries to the cult.

---

Here's a list of potential victims, and the rewards they give, when you *don't* sell them out to the cult.

#### Burial:

There's a woman lying on the ground, surrounded by digging men. She's about to be buried alive. The creeps carry quite a bit of cash around. Saving her doesn't instantly give you a reward; her father - a gangster - will be very happy if you do save her and wire $60'000 to your bank account after a while.

#### Domestic:

There's a man who's just been thrown out of his home by his wife, who suspects him to be cheating on her. He asks you to drive him to the golf club. Do that, and he'll give you $80, his contact info, and will become available as a "Hard" opponent to play golf against.

#### Drunk Driver 1:

Two men are arguing. One of them asks you to drive the drunk other home. Back home, the drunkard will give you $80 and pass out.

#### Drunk Driver 2:

A young couple ask you to drive them to their motel. At some point they'll nonchalantly have sex in your car. They reward you with $80. Since they are two people, delivering them to the cult awards $2000.

#### Escape Paparazzi:

An actress wants to avoid Paparazzi, because she's not wearing enough make-up. She'll pay $750 for your troubles.

#### Getaway Driver:

Two robbers threatening a merchant at gunpoint ask you to help them get away. Do it, and they'll give you a $1000 cut. One of them turns out to be none other than Packie McReary from *GTA IV*, a fairly skilled Gunman for use in future heists.

#### Hitch Lift 2:

[Hitch Lift 1 is not a potential cult victim; this is not a typo]
A woman with red backpack asks you to drive her back home. The reward for doing so is her contact info.

#### Hitch Lift 3:

A woman is waiting for a car to stop and pick her up. She wants you to take her to a broadcasting station close by the Vinewood sign in order to surprise her boyfriend. The only reward you'll ever get, is her boyfriend threatening to punch your teeth out, if you don't knock him out first. Oh, you could gun him down too, but where's the fun in that?

#### Hitch Lift 4:

A bride wants to escape from her groom. Why she ever agreed to marry him is a mystery, even to her. There is no reward for helping her.

#### Snatched:

A woman is being abducted by the Lost. You'll have to kill them, then save her. She'll ask you to drop her off someplace, where a friend will pick her up. She won't give you any reward, despite having to deal with a hail of bullets, talk about ungrateful...

Comment: The **Burial**: just finished it with Franklin and in couple of minutes got a phone call from that girl who said that her father was happy, bla-bla and got $60k for it

Comment: @Novarg Ah yes, now I remember. The guide didn't mention it and the Burial was one of the first random encounter I had played, so I completely forgot about the phone call. Thanks for reminding me, I edited my answer now.

Comment: I delivered all potential victims to their destinations and didn't really receive much for them. Is there any way to delivery other randomness to the althruists or not ?

Comment: @Emma Apparently, driving guests around in a taxi also counts, but I've never done it myself, so I don't know. Feel free to edit my answer when you know more about it; I won't be able to verify myself for at least a couple of months.

Answer (score -2):

It's unknown if some events are repeatable.  Several events can give you stock in a business, or experience in a skill.

Helping the heist driver who is bleeding out on the medium of a highway will, for example, net you a heist member (who is cheaper and after one heist will be upgraded 25%), driver experience and less than $400.

As for the cult, you could just try to kidnap people like in Saints Row by having them in the back seat or by maybe taxi missions.  But it needs testing.